# Firebird/Interbase - create new user/view without SYSDBA

Tags: firebird, interbase, sysdba

I'm developing app that need data from Firebird DB. Guy that create this DB forgot SYSDBA password and I need create new user or just view. Other apps that communicate with DB have also unknown users. But I can connect to the DB server so I see DB file system. I know that MySQL has backdoor, Firebird should has too, right?

Answer (score 3):

Firebird does not have a backdoor as such. But you can move the database to another Firebird install (or use the `security2.fdb` from another Firebird install) where you do know the password of `SYSDBA`.

Other options include resetting the password by logging in as a member of the `RDB$ADMIN` role, but this assumes this was granted earlier by `SYSDBA` both in the security database and one normal database. Or using trusted authentication as a member of the Windows administrator group. However under Firebird 2.5 this requires that `AUTO ADMIN MAPPING` is enabled for the security database (which isn't the default).

See [SQL user management commands](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-security-auth-manage-users) for details.

That said, it is advisable to make a 'normal' user the owner and `RDB$ADMIN` of the database and use that user for adding or modifying the structure of the database (but in this case that would most likely require the SYSDBA account).